# Can anyone explain this if condition in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

```
IF(ISNULL(@ApproachId, 0) = 0)
```

Please explain this expression - what is the meaning of this `if` condition and what result would it return?

Comment: If approachid is null or zero the expression evaluates to true

Comment: Otherwise, false

Answer (score 1):

It's semantically the same as

```
IF(@Approachid IS NULL OR @ApproachId = 0)
```

It's just harder to read.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This condition checks whether "@ApproachId" is equal to zero or not. In case "@ApproachId" is a null value then it will be considered as zero.